# How to get only group product in Rest API woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I create many products on my woocommerce store now I want only group products not simple or variation products in the rest of API.

can anyone assist me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the 'type' parameter in api end point

Product type. Options: simple, grouped, external and variable. Default is simple.

POST: /wp-json/wc/v3/products?type='grouped'